# Javascript Order of Events

Tags: javascript, image

just wanted to ask a quick question if I may regarding a simple JavaScript function I've cobbled together. This is not my forte at all so it's taken me some time just to get it working, but since I don't have that much of an understanding on the flow of things, I do have a question which I'm struggling to find an answer for / understand for myself. I'm hoping it will be simple enough for whoever's reading this.

All this script does is allow you to select some files (images) and then it gives you the base64 data for however many you have selected.

At the bottom of the script after the while loop is:

```
console.log("Returned values: " + imageList);
```

But it produces nothing in the console log *unless* I put something like this in the line before it. That's my question really, why do I need to do that? I'm sure it's just my understanding (or lack of) on how things are executed.

```
alert ("hello");
```

```js
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

  var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
  var arrayCounter = 0;
  var imageList = [];

  while (arrayCounter < filesSelected.length) {

    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[arrayCounter];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {

      var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // base64 data
      alert("Converted Base64 version is " + srcData); // alert showing data
      imageList.push(srcData);
    }

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    arrayCounter++;
  }

  alert("hiya");
  console.log("Returned values: " + imageList)

}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL -->

<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="true" style="opacity: 100" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same console output (which is just `Returned values:`) with our without the `alert` and this is just as it should be. The `alert` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Also, please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then you question is meaningless here. Just include your code in a "code snippet" (which I have done for you) and then it's all right here and we can run it as well as easily copy it to our answers.

Comment: You need to read about callbacks. The console.log is executed before imageList.push which executes when the fileReader load event is fired. Hence no result in console.log. Put that log inside that callback, I mean wher you push it.

Comment: I wasn't expecting replies back so soon!
Scott, apologies about the "code snippet" functionality and Satish thanks for your answer, I'll have a play in a minute and read about these callbacks.